# php list in array files in dir and sub dirs etc. that match pattern.

Tags: php, file, design-patterns, directory

I'm looking to list all the files in a dir and its sub dirs that match a pattern and return the list as an array for later use.  I would actually like to pass an array of dirs to do this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dirs= new ArrayIterator(array('./', '/dir_two'));
$list = array();
foreach($dirs as $dir){
    $dir_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir_iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

    foreach($iterator as $file){
        if(preg_match('~.*~',$file->getFilename()))
                array_push($list,$file->getPathname());
    }
}
print_r($list);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php), but it might be that the patterns do not have enough expressive power for your needs. It uses the same patterns that are used by the shell, not regular expressions.